# I can't stop loop in react js when i'm using ccomponentDidUpdate with axios

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I'm componentDidUpdate with axios and update state I get infinite loop.
So, I have created a below simple component but I get infinite loop happening.

**This is my code source:**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import HeaderItem from './HeaderItem';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";  
class categorie extends React.Component{
state={
    content:[]
 }
 componentDidMount()
 {
    this.getContent();
 }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
        if(this.state.content!==prevState.content)
        {
            this.getContent();
        }
    }

getContent=()=>{
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/article?categorie=${this.props.match.params.id}`).then((res)=>{
        this.setState({
            content:res.data.filter(data=>data.categorie==this.props.match.params.id)
        })      
    })
}

render(){
return (  
 <div>
     <div className="container">
         <div className="row">
                 {this.state.content.map(data=>(
                     <h1>{data.title}</h1>
                 ))}
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 );
}
}
export default categorie;
```

Comment: `this.state.content!==prevState.content` will always be `true` because you're comparing arrays, which will always point to different objects in memory. If you must execute this code in `componentDidUpdate`, you'll need to find a different way to determine if your data are new.

Comment: Why do you need to fetch data during `componentDidUpdate` instead of just doing it during mount?

Comment: i use componentDidUpdate because i have a navbar with categorie link (travel,games) and i want when i click travel for example get data from json-server with this categorie and push this data a component categorie i try componentdidmount but the component not reload

Comment: So it sounds like you shouldn’t be triggering a new fetch based on content equality but rather it should happen if your category link changes

Answer (score 0):

if your data coming as an array, then your condition will always be true, and this would make your function always work

```
[1, 2] !== [1, 2] // true
```

you can compare the two arrays by stringifying the content of both arrays and compare:

you need to use `json.stringify` for comparing objects of the array

or you can use **lodash** `._isEqual` to compare.

I recommend: using react hook `useEffect` and change to a functional component.

Comment: Each item in the content array is an object; this won't work

Comment: It could if ordering is guaranteed

Answer (score 0):

Is it happening for this component specifically or it’s parent? The parent can trigger re-renders of component as well. 
Do you see multiple `get` requests?

Comment: this component specifically,i have a navbar with categorie link (travel,games) and i want when i click travel for example get data from json-server with this categorie and push this data a component categorie i try componentdidmount but the component not reload